# How to change color of a specific section on a web page?

Tags: css, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

How can I change the color of a certain section in a web page ?
It is located above the footer. I want to make like 10px height and width that takes all the page. i will include social icons in that space.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a class to the element you want to style. Let's say you want to change the background of a `<section>` element and the height and width you need, you can add a `class="mysection"`

Then you can add a CSS file or a `style` tag at the `head` of your HTML document with the following code:

```
.mysection {
   background-color: red;
   width: 100%;
   height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: `<section>` is a block element, so the width attribute may be unnecessary. For answering a question that says "and width that takes all the page" however, it makes sense!

Comment: @Frish You're right, forgot that for a sec, thanks for the correction!

Comment: @IvanS95 Thank you for your answer but how can I define the location of this section. It is just above the footer. I'm using wordpress, will I face limitations in editing? I see I can change in css editor but I don't know how to tag this specific section.

Comment: @MariamMamdouh it might help to show us more of the structure you are facing, if you can edit HTML, then you should add a class to the `section` like: `<section class="yourclass">`, if you can't edit HTML, then you might be able to target it with CSS only depending on the structure you have

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `<div>` tag  or `<section`> tag. While applying styles in HTML, it should mention inside the `<style>` tag in the header section

Example

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #test {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="test">
    Test
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```